# RegEx - Match Words in Same Sentence with Negative Lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, sentence

I'm trying to match a word (good) if another word (bad) does not exist in the same sentence. I want to do this using [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as I want only the first word (good) to be included in the captured results.

Here's my regular expression:

```
(?<!\bbad\b[^.])\bgood\b(?![^.]+\bbad\b)
```

This does work in all cases except when the word I'm looking for (good) precedes the other word (bad).

So in the following examples, the results are as follows:

1. TEST 1: A good example of a bad regex. (no matches - PASS)
2. TEST 2: A bad example of a good regex. **(match found - FAIL)**
3. TEST 3: A bad example. A good regex.   (match found - PASS)
4. TEST 4: A good example. A bad regex.   (match found - PASS)

Can someone please point me to what I'm missing here? [Here's my test on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I8wfps/1/).

Comment: So `bad` must not come after `good` in same sentence?

Comment: @anubhava. Yes, "bad" must not come before or after "good" in the same sentence. If "bad" appears after "good", my regex works. But the regex fails if "bad" appears before "good" in the same sentence.

Comment: Just to mention, it is also possible by [matching what you don't need but capture what you want](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): [`[^.]*\bbad\b[^.]*|(\bgood\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/e3SC5T/1) (If you can use this, depends on your task. It requires to programmatically check, if group 1 is set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?:^|\.)(?:(?!\b(?:bad|good)\b)[^.])*(\bgood\b)(?![^.]+\bbad\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2GYpAf/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|\.)`: Match start position or a dot
- `(?:(?!\b(?:bad|good)\b)[^.])*`: Match a non dot character if doesn't have word `good` or `bad` ahead. Repeat this match 0 or more times
- `(\bgood\b)`: Match full word `good`
- `(?![^.]+\bbad\b)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have one or more non-dot characters followed by the word, `bad` ahead of the current position

Comment: Here are all the [Unit Tests](https://regex101.com/r/2GYpAf/3)

Answer (score 2):

If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you can optionally repeat the character class, exluding matching a newline.

```
(?<!\bbad\b[^.\n]*)\bgood\b(?![^.\n]+\bbad\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\bbad\b[^.\n]*)` Negative lookbehind, assert to the left is not the word `bad` followed by optional chars exluding a `.` or newline
- `\bgood\b` Match the word `good`
- `(?![^.\n]+\bbad\b)` Negative lookahead, assert to the right is not optional chars excluding `.` or newline and the word `bad`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ucmHg9/1)

Comment: This is good regex for flavors such as modern Javascript

Comment: That is a very clean expression. I am using it in C# .NET Core and quantifiers are supported in the lookbehind. So I will use your solution. Thank you!